# the induced homomorphism $i_\#:\pi_1(P,x_0) \to \pi_1 (X,x_0)$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $P$ is a path component of $X$ and $X_0\in P$, then the inclusion map $i:P\to X$ can be regarded as a map of pointed spaces $P(X.x_0) \to (X,x_0)$. Prove that the induced homomorphism $i_\#:\pi_1(P,x_0) \to \pi_1 (X,x_0)$ is an isomorphism.

here I need to show that $i$ has an inverse but how?
can someone help me please

Comment: It is easier to show that it is onto. If $\gamma$ is a path in $X$ and $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = X_0$, then $\gamma(t)\in P$ for all $t$.

Comment: how can I able to show that it is 1-1

Comment: That's similar, the homotopy must also stay in $P$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $i_\#$ is injective: Assume that for two loops $\gamma, \gamma'$ the images of their classes are equal under $i_\#$. This means that $[i\gamma]=[i\gamma']$ in $\pi_0(X,x_0)$, so their is a pointed homotopy $H:\gamma\simeq\gamma'$. This $H$ is a map from $I\times I$, so its image must be path-connected. Hence $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are homotopic in $P$.

Surjectivity is even easier: A loop $\gamma$ in at $x_0$ in $X$ is also a loop in $P$.

Comment: What do you mean by a pointed homotopy ? Isn't a homotopoy between $i\gamma$ and $i\gamma'$? I don't follow the argument.

Comment: @Alex: By a pointed homotopy I meant a homotopy which leaves the endpoints fixed, usually called a *path homotopy*. Since $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are loops, we can regard them as maps from the circle $S^1$ to $X$, sending some basepoint $s_0$ to $x_0$, and a path homotopy between them is then a homotopy on $S^1 \times I \to X$ leaving $s_0$ fixed, that's why I called it a *pointed homotopy*.

Comment: Ok I see; but how to you conclude that is a pointed homotopy between $\gamma$ and $\gamma'?$ We have a pointed homotopy between $i\gamma$ and $i\gamma'.$

Comment: @Alex: $i:P\to X$ is simply the inclusion map sending each point $p\in P$ to $p\in X$. A homotopy $i\gamma\simeq i\gamma'$ is a map $H: I\times I \to X$ such that $H(s,0)=i(\gamma(s))$ and $H(s,1)=i(\gamma'(s))$. Since $i\gamma$ is a loop in the component $P$ of $X$, the image of $H$ is entirely contained in $P$. That is why we can regard $H$ as a map $I\times I \to P$.

Comment: Or, if you want to be really precise, you can say: There is a map $\tilde H: I \times I \to P$ such that $i\circ\tilde H = H$, and this $\tilde H$ is the path homotopy we are looking for.

Comment: @Alex: Depending on your background in point-set topology, it is more or less easy to see that $\tilde H$ is continuous.

Comment: Hum but $i$ is continuous and $H$ as well then it follow that $H^\sim$ is continuous. isn't the existence of $H^\sim$  which is "more or less easy to see"?

Comment: @Alex: Careful! The continuity of $i$ is not what makes $\tilde H$ continuous. That would work if we had $i\circ H = \tilde H$. But it is $i \circ \tilde H = H$. The construction of $\tilde H$ is simple: For any $(s,t)\in I \times I$, regard $H(s,t) \in X$ as a point in $P$, and take this point as the image of $(s,t)$ under $\tilde H$.

Comment: arf, yes, sorry. I need to think. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! It sometimes helps to draw a diagram to not get confused with the maps and how they relate to each other. @Alex